# CakePhp: On the fly associations using a re-named Model field?

Tags: cakephp, associations

I'm trying to use on the fly associations to trim down the data I retrieve, but the model I'm using is associated to other models with a re-named field because I have 2 of the same models associated with it.

So, here's the model, say 'test', that has two 'user' fields, both related to the User model.

In the model:

```
  var $belongsTo = array( 
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id' 
    ),
    'User_Watched' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id_watched' 
    )
);
```

When I retrieve data related to 'test', I want to only retrieve particular data linked to the 'User' and 'User_Watched' fields without any other nested information.

But when I do:

```
 $this->User->unbindModel(array('hasMany' => array('something1', 'something2')), false);
```

then something1 and something2 data does not show up for the 'User' field of model 'test', but is still retrieved for the 'User_watched' field.

Can I not retrieve unwanted data for the 'User_watched' field?

Hope this makes sense... :)

Answer (score 2):

> to use on the fly associations to trim
>   down the data I retrieve

Good idea.

```
'foreignKey' => 'user_id_watched'
```

should possibly be:

`'foreignKey' => 'user_watched_id'`.

Edit 1: At least this would make sense according to my current understanding. If `user_id` is a correct foreign key(FK), which cakephp uses to unbind the relations, but `user_id_watched` isn't, than your described behavior is explained.

Edit 2: The Containable behavior gives you another tool for controlling associated models.

Comment: Thank you, benjamin.  Why would it have to be ending with 'id'? the actual field in the 'Test' model is 'user_id_watched.
I did solve this using 'joins'.

Comment: Hello KcYxA,
Cakephp uses the `Convention over Configuration` approach, meaning that if a developer sticks to some conventions, cakephp in exchange reduces the amount of configuration needed. 
In the case at hand, `user_id_watched` functions as a FK. FK's in cakephp should follow convention, so the fieldname in the table should be `user_watched_id`. Then of course all occurrences of the old name have to be changed accordingly.
If this works out for you, please let me know so that I can melt this comment in the answer above.
Kind regards, Benjamin.

Answer (score 2):

KcYxA,

Containable behavior might help a lot in this case, as benjamin mentioned, your "find" queries would look like:

```
$this->User->find('first', array(
      'conditions' => array('User.id' => $id),
      'contain'    => array('UserWatched')
    ));
```

In this case, you won't have to use unbindModel method. In this example, you'll get User and UserWatched data.
If you need only User data from "find", then tell Cake to "$this->User->contain();" so it won't go further then User model.

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up using a join.

Comment: KcYxA,
using "hand-written" SQL should be last resort, as it bypasses the abstraction of the underlying database layer. In other words, a developer, who introduced SQL statements directly, has to rewrite these once he switches to another database/datasource.
Kind regards, Benjamin.

Comment: jujav4ik, it is still written using CakePHP's convention, where one adds a 'join' array to the parameters of the 'find' method.  But I understand and agree with your point.

Answer (score 0):

Change $primaryKey in fly, run controller
Sample:

// Models

//....

class PreProductoDescripcion extends AppModel {

```
/**
 * Primary key field
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $primaryKey = 'id_producto_descripcion';

//....
//....
```

}

class SenasaPedidosDetalles extends AppModel {

```
/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $displayField = 'cod_tango';

public $belongsTo = array(
    'SenasaPedidos' => array(
        'className' => 'SenasaPedidos',
        'foreignKey' => 'senasa_pedidos_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'PreProductoDescripcion' => array(
        'className' => 'PreProductoDescripcion',
        'foreignKey' => 'cod_tango',
        //'conditions' => array('SenasaPedidosDetalles.cod_tango' => 'PreProductoDescripcion.codigo'),
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

//....

#

```
// Controller Fly
//...
$this->SenasaPedidos->Behaviors->load('Containable');
$this->SenasaPedidos->SenasaPedidosDetalles->PreProductoDescripcion->primaryKey = 'codigo';
                    $datos = $this->SenasaPedidos->find(
                            'first', array(
                        'fields' => array( 'SenasaPedidos.*' ),
                        'conditions' => array( 'SenasaPedidos.id' => $id ),
                        'contain' => array(
                            'Usuarios' => array(
                                'fields' => array( 'Usuarios.apellido_nombre' )
                            ),
                            'Clientes' => array(
                                'fields' => array( 'Clientes.razon_social' )
                            ),
                            'Provincias' => array(
                                'fields' => array( 'Provincias.nombre' )
                            ),
                            'Transportes' => array(
                                'fields' => array( 'Transportes.razon_social' )
                            ),
                            'SenasaPedidosDetalles' => array(
                                'fields' => array( 'SenasaPedidosDetalles.*' ),
                                'PreProductoDescripcion' => array(
                                    'fields' => array(
                                        'PreProductoDescripcion.id_producto_descripcion',
                                        'PreProductoDescripcion.descripcion'
                                    )
                                )
                            ),
                        )
                    ));
//...
```